# Build executable for other linux systems

Tags: c++, linux, dynamic, cross-platform

Is is possible to build a dynamic linked cpp program on a build server ( Ubuntu **14.4** ) for a host system ( Ubuntu **16.4** )?

The third party libs are compiled separately for 14.4 and 16.4.
Trouble:Running the 14.4 binary on 16.4 results in `undefined symbols` which contain strings from the third party library.
The command `ldd -d -r` returns a couple of `undefined symbols`.

Question:

- I know that gcc compiles this binary for this specific machine, which causes the error, but what precisely is causing the error? Libs are on both machines and I'm kind of sure that they are compiled good.
- Are there some topics I could feed a search engine with, or a good book to read about his problem?
- Is it actually possible to do a *CrossCompile* from 14.4 to 16.4 or just a huge mess?
- could I solve this in compiling static instead dynamic?

Comment: Executables are compiled to specific processor instructions.  You would need to have both linux systems use the same make of processor.  For example, an executable for an Intel based linux system will not run on an ARM based linux system.

Comment: Could be a thing your Ubuntu 16.4 have 64bit libraries but application want to link 32bit? Also check a machine has a proper version of dependency. EDIT: assuming destination machines use x86  processors.

Comment: You can build for either system if you set up your build environment properly.  ie. that you have the right libraries and include files and set the paths to them when building.  One way to do this is in a chroot.

Comment: `make` and `gcc` are the same versions. @stark I've the feeling that that would be the best bet. Downloading an Ubuntu 16.4 clone into a chroot folder, as described in this link [Basics chroot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot). Afterwards compiling all used third party libraries for this folder and than compiling the actual cpp code with those libs? Have I gotten you right?